# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'lat' of 'location' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина ошибки.
Мне нужно при обновлении страницы сохранять данные в redux, а потом рендерить их.

Если закомментировать вывод на страницу, то в консоли сначала данные будут `undefined`, а потом уже то что нужно.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const getDetailed = async () => {
      const baseURL = 'https://api.json-generator.com/templates/N21r0eic2XEy/data';
      const token = 'wm3gg940gy0xek15ld986uaizhz83c6rh2sir9f9fu';
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
      };
      const { data } = await axios.get(baseURL, config);
      const detailedJob = data.filter((item) => item.id === id)[0];
      dispatch(setSelectedJob(detailedJob));
    };
    getDetailed();
  }, []);

const {
    title,
    address,
    benefits,
    location,
    email,
    pictures,
    salary,
    phone,
    description,
    employment_type,
  } = useSelector((state) => state.jobs.selectedJob);

const { lat, long } = location;
  const position = {
    lat,
    lng: long,
  };
```

Comment: Причина ошибки это то что ваш **location** undefined. когда компонент рендерится, данных нет, это надо учитывать. Проверьте ваше хранилище на наличие location и его значения

Comment: Действительно, почему то нету. Такое впечатление что useEffect не отрабатывает. Не подскажите, с чем это может быть связано ?

Comment: Да кто же его знает.... Если **location** появляется только после возврата ответа внутри useEffect, то это асинхронная операция и стоит дождаться ответа. Один из вариантов, в хранилище redux определить значения по дефолту

Comment: А как можно дождаться ответа ? Я думал этим занимаются **async** i **await**.
Я был уверен что пока **useEffect** не отработает, до деструктуризации **location** просто не дойдет очередь.
А на деле, сначала данные из **location** вынимаются, а только потом записываются. Где то я упускаю важную деталь.

Comment: Все события реакт надо рассматривать как асинхронные. Реакт сначала устанавливает компонент с данными по умолчанию, позже, когда состояние меняется, он перерисовывает компонент под полученные значения. Защититься можно, допустим, создав изначально структуру ответа в хранилище, либо вынести обработку данных в `useEffect(() => {}, [selectorData])`, где проверять переменные на их значения. Рассматривайте useEffect как асинхроннаю операцию.